# Как привязать Textbox из UserControl к свойству VM в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Есть примитивный UserControl с textbox и checkbox. Если привязать свойство с текстом textbox к свойству во ViewModel страницы, где используется usercontrol, то при изменении текста в textbox не вызывается изменение привязанного своЙства. как это исправить?

Контрол:

```
public partial class LoginNameControl : UserControl
{
    public static  DependencyProperty NameUserProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "NameUser",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(LoginNameControl));

    public string NameUser
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NameUserProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NameUserProperty, value); }
    }

    public static  DependencyProperty IsCheckProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsCheck",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(LoginNameControl));

    public bool IsCheck
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsCheckProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsCheckProperty, value);
    }

    public LoginNameControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

ViewModel страницы:

```
public class LoginVM : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _nameuser;
    public string NameUser
    {
        get => _nameuser;
        set => Set(ref _nameuser, value, nameof(NameUser));
    }        
    
    private bool _ischeck;
    public bool Ischeck { 
        get => _ischeck;
        set => Set(ref _ischeck, value, nameof(Ischeck)); 
    }
}
```

разметка страницы:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:LoginVM/>
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="350"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="20"
            Width="250"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" ShadowDepth="1"/>
        </Border.Effect>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Controls:LoginNameControl 
                IsCheck="{Binding Ischeck}" 
                NameUser="{Binding NameUser}" 
                Grid.Row="1"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameUser}" Grid.Row="2" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="30"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Разметка UserControl:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="Text" Grid.Row="0" Background="LightGray" MinWidth="50" Text="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl, Path=NameUser}"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="Check" Grid.Row="1" Content="Test" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl, Path=IsCheck}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Text="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl, Path=NameUser, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" попробуйте

Comment: @Gardes Не работает. Даже если смотреть в отладке, то изменение просто не вызывается

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [WPF c# Binding, привязки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1156397/wpf-c-binding-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Небольшое дополнение к ответу @Gardes.

Для того, чтобы пользователи `UserControl`'а не должны были держать в голове, что привязку к `NameUser` нужно обязательно делать с опцией `Mode=TwoWay`, нужно определить установить режим привязки по умолчанию:

```
public static DependencyProperty NameUserProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "NameUser",
    typeof(string),
    typeof(LoginNameControl),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        null, // default value
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

При этом необходимость в `Mode=TwoWay` в точке использования контрола отпадает.

Comment: (Мне кажется, ответ @Gardes больше заслуживает галочку)

Answer (score 4):

добавить `Mode=TwoWay` здесь:

```
<Controls:LoginNameControl IsCheck="{Binding Ischeck}" 
                           NameUser="{Binding NameUser, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

и `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` здесь:

```
<TextBox x:Name="Text" Grid.Row="0" Background="LightGray" MinWidth="50" 
             Text="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl, Path=NameUser, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```